# using $function new operator in MongoDB for updateMany failed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an array tree and I want to update that array in my collection with this syntax

```
db.documents.updateMany(
  {
    companyId: ObjectId("5f29074048538b6403bc71ab",
    tree: {
      $in: [ObjectId("5f539bf696fa1748fa417b07")],
    },
  },
  [{
    $set: {
      tree: {
        $function: {
          body:
            "function(t) { t.push(ObjectId('5f5494a1d708bda4988d75d4')); return t.filter(v => [ObjectId('5f539bf696fa1748fa417b07')].includes(v))}}",
          args: ["$tree"],
          lang: "js",
        },
      },
    },
  }]
);
```

why I write body function with string? because in Golang I can't use code for bson, so I must use function string, the syntax above is I run on command line mongo cli to try there first then implement to my Go app

the error I got is

```
Unrecognized expression '$function'
```

anyone has same problem ? or I did wrong to use `$function` operator ??

Comment: it requires mongodb v4.4 and mongo shell v4.4, have you checked that?

Comment: yes I am using Mongo Atlas and it is 4.4 and my mongo shell as well, @turivishal

Comment: Okay, might be this expression will not work in $set, can you try this pipeline in aggregate() and instead of $set use $addFields or $project, check its working or not, provide some sample document will check for you.

Comment: I was got comment this also on mongo forum, , it required with "aggregate" but , if I use this , would it update the all document which I use "$addFields" ? because my mission here to manipulation data not showing the data

Comment: no this will not update with $addFields, can you check using $addFields in aggregation its working or not. add that forum link in your question, you can add your analysis in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. In my scenario, the problem was the version of MongoDB instance.
Check the documentation of $function https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/, it says the functions was introduced in version 4.4
If you have any doubts about the version you're running just execute "db.version()".
Mine was 4.2.17